# Break line after Icon in Menu Item Android

Tags: android, menu

Simple question that I don't find an answer for.

Is it possible to break line after the icon in a menu item making them not inline anymore? (The menu slides in from left by using NavigationView in Android support library)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/cards"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/card_icon"
        android:title="Cards" />

    ...
    ...
    ...

</group>
```

This is how I want it to look like.

[image: The desired look]

But instead they are aligned inline.

**Update after answer:**

Using a modified *android.R.layout.activity_list_item* (changed to vertical aligned left):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="1dip"
    android:paddingBottom="1dip"
    android:paddingStart="8dip"
    android:paddingEnd="8dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="24dip"
        android:layout_height="24dip"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I added an actionLayout to the menu items:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/cards"
    android:checked="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/cards_icon"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/vertical_menu_item"
    android:title="Cards" />
```

But nothing happens. They are still inline. I also tried using `app:showAsAction="always"` and `app:actionLayout="@layout/vertical_menu_item"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a custom view (eg: vertical layout with `ImageView` and `TextView`), and in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` you can use [`setActionView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView%28android.view.View%29) method of the [MenuItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html) to use this custom view as Item view.

---

Or from menu xml:

```
android:actionLayout="@[package:]layout/layout_resource_name"
```

Comment: Alright, so I create a vertical layout but how do I hook up the ImageView to the icon and the TextView to the text?

Comment: Use the **same id's** used in default android resource and the system will handle that.

Comment: Okey, thanks. That what I was thinking to. But Im not sure how to find the default layout? Is there an easy way to access it in the IDE?

Comment: You're welcome.  I did this before but i cant find in which project i have the  code, so i'm not sure but i think the default resource is called *android.R.layout.activity_list_item* (you can access it from your IDE), so the id's are *@android:id/text1* and *@+id/icon* . Give a try with that, and i'll be back if i find where i've used this before.

Comment: Ah thats right. I found them now and I set the actionLayout but it does not change. If you have any idea let my know. I will update my question with the code.

Comment: @nilsi I finally found the code! But i was wrong, android will not recongnize the id's. In my code, i've only one Item so i'm setting the image source and text in my custom xml file. In your case, from *onCreateOptionsMenu()*, you can call item.getActionView() to get the layout and then use *findViewById()* to get your *TextView* and *ImageView*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ended up putting the text in the image itself yesterday and skipped the title completely after trying for a few hours. I might go back and give this a try. Anyway, I accept your answer. It's close enough!